# How can I save a file to a specific "keyed" location?

Tags: mojave, macos

In Finder to go to a specific location I can do <kbd>Cmd-Shift-G</kbd>

But what if I want to save to a specific location? That is, I don't want to click through a folder hierarchy in the save dialogue box.

For example I would like to save the current file to `~/.ssh`

[image]

The **Where drop down** allows you to select a location, but I want to be able to enter the location using the keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Command -> Shift -> G in the save dialogue box too, just like in Finder.

Default Folder X is great for saving some as favorites or specific defaults for certain apps. IT does way more than just keyboard shortcuts, but that is one of its super-powers.

- https://www.apple.com/accessibility/mac/mobility/

Accessibility lets you use keyboard commands to select graphical elements and then tab / type / navigate to whatever folders you prefer.

[image: macos keyboard preferences for full keyboard access]

Control F7 allows tab to select more items and move around using your keyboard in the save dialog.